# Query Windows For ISO Currency String

Tags: c++, windows-xp, regional-settings

How can I query Windows to get the current regional settings for currency (e.g. USD, CAD, MX) per ISO standard? Not dollar-sign, for instance ($).

Comment: What ISO standard would that be? You've tagged this `C++`, are you refering to the ISO C++ standard (ISO/IEC 14882) ?

Comment: ISO 4217. Question was already answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/199244

It tells you, that you should use

```
GetUserDefaultLCID
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318135%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

and then

```
GetLocaleInfo
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318101%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: LCID lcid = LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT;
    TCHAR currency[5];
    GetLocaleInfo(lcid, LOCALE_SINTLSYMBOL, currency, 5);